# How to use Guzzle HTTP Client in simple PHP?

Tags: php, guzzle

I am currently using PHP CURL but somehow it is not working for `basicAUTH` in my case. I want to use guzzel HTTP client in simple PHP project (not a Laravel project). Every solution on the internet I found is setting up in laravel and installing it via composer.

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->post($service_url, [
    'auth' => [
        $username, 
        $admin_password
    ]
]);
```

or if guzzel do not works with simple PHP, Suggest other client which can work with simple PHP for basic Auth. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> First of all you need to navigate to your main forder you will be working in,  which reside inside htdocs as usual and then insall GuzzleHttpClient by using composer tool

> (Recommended: 2+ version)

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

It will download and install dependencies such as:

- symfony/deprecation-contracts
- psr/http-message
- psr/http-client
- guzzlehttp/promises
- ralouphie/getallheaders, etc.

> After getting it fully installed; try simple example to see if it really works

```
<?php
// First of all require autoload from vendor dir;
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
  
$client = new Client([
    // Base URI is used with relative requests
    'base_uri' => 'https://reqres.in',
]);
  
// The response to get
$res = $client->request('GET', '/api/users', [
    'query' => ['page' => '2', ]
]);
  
$body = $res->getBody();
$array_body = json_decode($body);
print_r($array_body);

?>
```

> Check the result in the browser

Answer (score 0):

Composer has nothing to do with Laravel or Guzzle, is "just" a package manager.
You can use - and I suggest to do so - composer in your project even if you're not using a framework.

Said that, once you have Guzzle source code (via composer or downloading directly the code; I would not reccommend the latter) you can just use it everywhere.

By the way I would suggest to use composer for two (main) reasons:

- You can keep under control dependencies (like Guzzle) in order to update/downgrade them easily. Also composer will track possible conflicts with other dependencies (that for instance can't work together under some circumstances)
- Composer has its own psr-4 autoloader

So yes, you can use Guzzle also without a framework and without composer, there's nothing preventing you to do so.